# How to create a new public page in a wordpress website using php

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I'm creating a php plugin for a Wordpress website that's meant to allow admins to approve or deny community submission. How it works is that there's a mysql database with information such as "title", "author", "content", etc for each submission. The php script looks at this information and stores it in an array for each post. It then stores those arrays in a single array that I can reference-- one 2D array, and it creates a GUI based on this array, where each post (each array within the larger array) has it's own approve or deny button. When the approve button is pressed for a specific post, it returns the index of the larger array that contains the information (taken from the mysql database) for that particular post, which I can get using `$_POST["approve"]`. Now, I have to make the actual page on the website, which I can probably do by taking a template html file and replacing certain bits of it so that it contains the right information. How would I then put this html file in the wordpress website? Is there a php function to do this for me?

Answer (score 0):

I actually did something similar just recently with a plugin to approve new members,
there are ultimately two ways you can go about it.
(I'm sure there's more but there are 2 ways that I know of haha)

1. is making a short code in your plugin and calling it on a page
2. is making a wordpress page template  **through your theme**  and having a page use that template

I tend to opt for shortcodes (because they're awesome!!) but how they are done in WordPress is quite simple

you make a PHP function like

```
function approve_content()
{
ob_start();
construct_layout();
return ob_get_clean();
}

function construct_layout();
{
  echo '
   <h3> This is my html stuff yay </h3>
  ';
}
```

At the bottom of the page you create a short code reference

```
//The shortcode code call would then be [approve_layout]
add_shortcode( 'approve_content', 'approve_layout' );
```

so now every time you call [approve_layout] on a page
`<h3> This is my html stuff yay </h3>` will display

Comment: Thank you! But is there a way I can add a new page to a wordpress website, instead of using a shortcode on an existing one?

Comment: Youll probably want a page template, which works by creating a page then assigning it to use a php template that has a html/css makeup ! in which case you need to make that through your current theme :)